# The value is not locked in android on click it is changeable

Tags: java, android

I created a game called tic tac toe to submit in collage, the app runs successfully but the main problem is that after clicking a button the value of that button is not locked on click.

In example if i click on button1 the value in button1 is stored X but when i click second time on that button1 the value is changing,

so the problem is how to lock the button value on click.

Thank you

Nothing Particularly tried but I want to solve this problem as fast as possible

Answer (score 0):

You can disable button view and click event after button click. `button.isClickable = false` This will disable the click event and `button.isEnabled = false` this will disable button view.

```
override fun onClick(v: View) {
    when (v.id) {
        R.id.button_id -> {
            button.isClickable = false
            button.isEnabled = false
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable that button in the onClick event of that button after you change its value.

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // write your code for changing the value of the button
            // ...
            // then disable it
            btn.setEnabled(false);
            btn.setClickable(false);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem by disabling the button when it is clicked once. To do that, you can use the following code:

```
YOUR_BUTTON.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //Your other code

            //Disable the button
            btn.setClickable(false);
            btn.setEnabled(false);
        }
    });
```

To re-enable the button, you can set the .setClickable() and .setEnabled() functions to true.

To do it in Kotlin:

```
YOUR_BUTTON.setOnClickListener {
    //Your other code
 
    YOUR_BUTTON.isEnabled = false
    YOUR_BUTTON.isClickable = false
}
```

To re-enable, you can set both parameters to true.